# Forcing re-election in RAFT

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, raft

I'm using Raft consensus, in hyperledger fabric, and I have some questions about how does it work.

1. Once a Leader is elected, does the orderer stays a leader until he goes down ?
2. Is it possible to force re-election process without restarting the leader container (docker restart orderer...) but with some options in the config block ( something like : ForceReElectionEvery: 60m ) ?
3. What kind of information is exchanged between the orderers cluster ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There is a new election launched by follower/s after an `ElectionTick` period without receiving messages from the leader. Take a look at https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/raft_configuration.html#channel-configuration.
2. As told in 1, a new leader election starts after `ElectionTick` without receiving messages from the leader. To modify `ElectionTick` once the channel has been created, you have to use `configtxlator` tool and update the channel, which is tedious.
3. Basically consensus on the ordering of transactions in blocks and blocks in the channel's chain. For more information: https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/orderer/ordering_service.html.

Take into account that there is an independent Raft consensus process per channel. Each channel has its own leader and leader election process.

Comment: I've used the following options:  "options": {
                  "election_tick": 10,
                  "heartbeat_tick": 1,
                  "max_inflight_blocks": 5,
                  "snapshot_interval_size": 20971520,
                  "tick_interval": "500ms"
                }
I've been watching the logs of my orderers but I did not see the re-election process for now.

And if my current leader goes rogue for a reason or another, my whole network will be in troubles, no ?

Comment: Have you created any channel?

Comment: Yes i have the sys channel and another channel "channel1"

Comment: Here's an example of one of the orderers logs : https://imgur.com/J9AHrXV and as you can see from yesterday 2020-03-03 17:03:36.465 (when I launched the orderers) there is no new election.

Comment: OK. While the follower keeps receiving any message from the leader, it seems that there is no new election. After an `ElectionTick` period without receiving messages, the follower/s launch the election process. I edit my answer.

Comment: But, when your leader goes down (or looses connection) another one replaces it after the election.

Comment: Yes, this works. I've tested it (docker stop orderer X and another orderer was elected as a leader)